# How to sort an array in Swift

Tags: swift

I want the Swift version of this code:

```
NSArray *sortedNames = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/swift/ for basics (including sorting)
var sortedStrings = sorted(stringArray) { $0.uppercaseString < $1.uppercaseString }

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
var names = [ "Alpha", "alpha", "bravo"]
var sortedNames = names.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

Update: Providing explanation as per recommendation of a fellow SO user.

Unlike ObjC, in Swift you have sorted() (and sort()) method that takes a closure that you supply that returns a Boolean value to indicate whether one element should be before (true) or after (false) another element. The $0 and $1 are the elements to compare. I used the localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare to get the result you are looking for. Now, localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare returns the type of ordering, so I needed to modify it to return the appropriate bool value.

Update for Swift 2:
`sorted` and `sort` were replaced by `sort` and `sortInPlace`

Comment: Please explain how this code works.  This minimizes the tendency to copy and paste without clear understanding.

Comment: There's definitely no "sorted" method, should be sort. I verified on Swift2.0

Comment: @Jacky - yes, it changed in Swift 2

Comment: It works only if I use sort() instead of sorted. I'm using Xcode 7.3. Can't say if the result is the intended in the original code.

Comment: @Tel - the original code is pre-Swift 2.0. There is an update from 2015 that states that you need to use `sort` instead of `sorted` in Swift 2

Comment: sortInPlace changes the original array, sort returns a new array, that's the difference

Comment: let names = [ "Alpha", "alpha", "bravo"]
        let sortedNames = names.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }

Comment: `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:` (`NSArray`) does not take a closure? It's older than Swift at all.

Answer (score 22):

### Sorting an Array in Swift

Define a initial names array:

```
var names = [ "gamma", "Alpha", "alpha", "bravo"]
```

**Method 1:**

```
var sortedNames = sorted(names, {$0 < $1})
// sortedNames becomes "[Alpha, alpha, bravo, gamma]"
```

This can be further simplified to:

```
var sortedNames = sorted(names, <)
// ["Alpha", "alpha", "bravo", "gamma"]
var reverseSorted = sorted(names, >)
// ["gamma", "bravo", "alpha", "Alpha"]
```

**Method 2:**

```
names.sort(){$0 < $1}
// names become sorted as this --> "[Alpha, alpha, bravo, gamma]"
```

Comment: `var names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]`


`var sortedNames = sorted(names, {$0 < $1})`

`print(sortedNames)`

`var sortedNames2: () = names.sort(){$0 < $1}`
`print(sortedNames2)`

Why is sortedNames2 returning an empty array??
Thanks

Comment: Thank you. It helped me very much.

Answer (score 17):

If your array does not contain Custom Objects (just a string or number type):

```
var sortedNames = sorted(names, <)
```

Otherwise if you create a Custom Data Object Class containing custom properties inside:

```
customDataObjectArray.sort({ $0.customProperty < $1.customProperty })
```

Answer (score 7):

### Most efficient way of sorting in SWIFT

The use of **Operator Overloading** is the most efficient way to sort Strings in Swift language.

```
// OPERATOR OVERLOADING
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
var sortedNames = sorted(names, <)
var reverseOrder = sorted(names, >)
```

In above code `>` and `<` operators  are overloaded in Swift to sort Strings.

I have test the code in Playground and conclude that when we use operator overloading it is best for sorting Strings.

Copy below to Playground.

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]

var reversed = sorted (names,
    // This is a closure
    { (s1 : String, s2 : String) -> Bool in
        return s1 > s2
    }
)
println(reversed)

var reverseOrder = sorted(names, {s1, s2 in s1 > s2})

var reverseOrder2 = sorted(names, { $0 > $1} )

// OPERATOR OVERLOADING
var reverseOrder3 = sorted(names, >)
```

The conclusion from Playground:

[image]

From above image you can see that all other ways needs to enumerate loops for sorting 5 strings. Where as when we use Operator overloading it does not required to enumerate loop to sort strings.

Referenced from **[Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)**

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort your array in ascending order then use below syntax:

```
var arrayName = sorted(arrayName, <)
```

as the **sorted()** is the predefined function in swift and < is used to indicate that the array should be sorted in ascending order. If you want to sort the array in descending order then simply replace **<** with **>** as I have shown below:

```
var arrayName = sorted(arrayName, >)
```

Comment: In swift 2: arrayName = arrayName.sort(>)

Answer (score 2):

You can usually use the built-in

```
func sort<T : Comparable>(inout array: [T])
```

but if you want to use `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`, your code can be translated directly using `NSArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Any method that can be used with Objective-C `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` can be used with Swift `sort` (or `sorted`) provided the type of thing in the array is known. So, in your code:

```
var arr : [String] = // ...
// it is an array of String, so we can use localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:
sort(&arr) {return $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .OrderedAscending}
```

Similarly:

```
var events : [EKEvent] = // ...
sort(&events) {return $0.compareStartDateWithEvent($1) == .OrderedAscending}
```

Comment: There's an obvious pattern here, and it would be nice to express that pattern so that you can convert the selector to a Swift function automatically, but I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift-**

```
let students: Set = ["Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku", "Akosua"]
let sortedStudents = students.sorted()
print(sortedStudents)
// Prints "["Abena", "Akosua", "Kofi", "Kweku", "Peter"]"
```

To sort the elements of your sequence in descending order, pass the greater-than operator (>) to the sorted(isOrderedBefore:) method.

```
let descendingStudents = students.sorted(isOrderedBefore: >)
print(descendingStudents)
// Prints "["Peter", "Kweku", "Kofi", "Akosua", "Abena"]"
```